# Filtrar ultimo dato por nombre en mysql

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Llevo intentando filtrar dispositivos de una base de datos sin resultados hasta ahora.

Lo que quiero hacer es tomar el ultimo registro de un nombre de dispositivo y mostrarlo, muestro una tabla de ejemplo:

| id | dispositivo | reg_date | reg_time | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | device_111 | 11-11-11 | 11:11:11 | Online |
| 2 | device_111 | 11-11-11 | 11:11:11 | Online |
| 3 | device_111 | 11-11-11 | 11:11:12 | Online |
| 4 | device_112 | 11-11-11 | 11:11:12 | Offline |
| 5 | device_112 | 11-11-11 | 11:11:13 | Offline |
| 6 | device_112 | 11-11-11 | 11:11:13 | Offline |
| 7 | device_113 | 11-11-11 | 11:11:14 | Online |
| 8 | device_113 | 11-11-11 | 11:11:14 | Online |
| 9 | device_113 | 11-11-11 | 11:11:15 | Online |

Lo que quiero obtener de esto es filtrar lo repetido y tomar el ultimo registro de cada dispositivo como se muestra a continuacion.

| id | dispositivo | reg_date | reg_time | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | device_111 | 11-11-11 | 11:11:12 | Online |
| 6 | device_112 | 11-11-11 | 11:11:13 | Offline |
| 9 | device_113 | 11-11-11 | 11:11:15 | Online |

Estoy intentando hacerlo con una query similar a esta (Pero aun sin resultados):

```sql
SELECT * FROM mitabla ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 10;
```

No he podido con dar con la solucion... agradezco las respuestas constructivas

Comment: Por qué el nombre del dispositivo aparece repetido?

Comment: Por que estan en una tabla donde hay mas de 200 dispositivos y contienen mayor columnas de datos

Comment: Ok, desde mi pobre perspectiva eso no está bien pues se está generando redundancia de datos y por ahí podría existir un cambio y en consecuencia una query distinta

Comment: Pero es posible lo que quiero hacer? Seleccionar el ultimo registro de cada nombre de dispositivo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que ya logre lo que dijiste, algo asi es

```
SELECT * FROM mitabla GROUP BY dispositivo HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Comment: Gracias crack, sos clave!